# How do I switch from ethernet to WIFI (and vice versa) without losing connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

I there a way to switch between ethernet and WIFI connections without losing connection?

I am downloading a huge file via Firefox without an option to resume.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on Windows? Example: you download a big file on WiFi, you notice WiFi speed is the limiting factor, and then you plug your compuer with the ethernet cable, but the connection used for the download is *still* WiFi. If I disconnect WiFi, then the connection is totally lost.

Comment: @FormerlyPimpJuiceIT Thank you for your comments. A download manager is helpful in some situations (I already used one in the past), but here I was more looking for a general solution, that also works for other programs than a browser.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to switch between ethernet and WIFI connections without losing connection?

Not in practice. The "connection" between Firefox and the remote server means that there is a local port on your local address, bound to a remote port on the server address.

The "local address" is bound to the network device, and you cannot (easily) have two network devices having the same address - they would conflict. So you'd need to bring down one device, and bring up the other device, with the same address.

But this is not enough since the internal structures that keep track of port and data being sent and received were bound to the old network device and would be destroyed when it goes down.

So you would need either an operating system kernel that is aware of the possibility or a virtual network device that is also aware of the possibility, and can present a single network interface to the operating system while juggling the devices in the background. This is called "[link aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation)".

On a "vanilla" system, I'm afraid you can do nothing.

I have tried bringing down a connection and moving the IP address on a different network device while downloading, but, even when Firefox is "frozen" before the down and "thawed" afterwards, the connection gets broken. I imagine this is because all the TCP connection parameters need to be reset, so the **server** must support resumption.

The connection **does not go down** if Firefox is connected to a router with three interfaces (one downlink to Firefox, two uplinks), and I juggle the two uplinks. The download stops briefly and I see packets being retried, and bounced; then the download resumes normally.

This is because, I believe, all the parameters "live" on the Firefox machine and on the server machine, and neither is affected by the juggle (the PC always sees the server at the same IP, and the server always sees the PC at the same IP via the NAT border router).

```
                              A-------------A
[ Firefox PC ] --e-- [ router ]             [ NAT ] --- [ server ]
                              B-------------B
```

Answer (score 3):

Generating a 'no route to host' error is the primary cause of reset TCP connections.  To avoid this, there cannot be an instant where both interfaces are down.  Also, there cannot be an instant when both interfaces are without an IP address, and a default route must remain in place at all times.

Make sure both your interface adapters are up, and have unique IP addresses.

Make sure default route is either not exclusive to a particular interface, or is present for both interfaces.  On my Mac:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.2.1        UGSc            5        4     en0
default            192.168.2.1        UGScI           0        0     en1
```

The second route is marked I for Inactive.

When I want to switch from en0 (wired) to en1 (wifi), I change the interface order in my System Preferences, putting WiFi above Ethernet.  I then check my network traffic stats to confirm that traffic is going over WiFi, in both directions.  I can then disconnect my Ethernet.

Using the same principles, this method will allow you to switch interfaces on other OSes:

## Both interfaces must not go down at the same time and a valid default route has to always be in place.

This implies that both interfaces have to have their own unique IP addresses pre-assigned before switching.

Answer (score 2):

You may be asking for [Multipath TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_TCP), which as far as I know doesn't exist on Windows:

[image]

Software that might emulate it (all are commercial)
but without guarantee as I never used them:

- [Speedify](https://speedify.com/)
- [WinGate](https://www.wingate.com/)

Answer (score 2):

As you did not specify the Operating System you are using, I will assume it is Windows 10.

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is that the TCP protocol is stateless, so if one network path goes down it may pick up the download on the other path.  It is possible that the download on Firefox will pause when the network link is disrupted and resume when it can re-contact the server.  It is quite likely, however, that your download will fail.  If this happens, you can go to the downloads window and click the "resume" button on the download, which "should" cause it to resume from where it left off.

Pro tip: If this is a critical file I would let it finish downloading.